# Create a dataframe from a dictionary with two pairs of keys and values

Tags: python, pandas

My dictionary look like this:

```
dic = {
'symbol': 'IFF',
'annualReports': [
{'Date': '2019', 'Currency': 'USD', 'Revenue': '514'},
{'Date': '2018', 'Currency': 'USD', 'Revenue': '256'},
{'Date': '2017', 'Currency': 'USD', 'Revenue': '256'}
]}
```

I would like to convert it into a dataframe and it has symbol and the first row of annualReports. The result look like this:

```
    symbol    Date     Currency     Revenue
0   IFF       2019     USD          514
```

I know how to convert to a dataframe from a single dictionary, the code like this:-

```
import pandas as pd

data = dic['annualReports'][0]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

And the output is like this:

```
    Date     Currency     Revenue
0   2019     USD          514
```

Therefore, may I know how to add symbol into the dataframe?

Comment: Working on an answer, but you should probably rename the variable `dict` since that's also the name of the class it's using and you'll have trouble accessing the class constructor once the variable's defined.

Comment: ok. let me rename the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `json_normalize`:

```
pd.json_normalize(dct, 'annualReports', ['symbol'])
```

---

```
   Date Currency Revenue symbol
0  2019      USD     514    IFF
1  2018      USD     256    IFF
2  2017      USD     256    IFF
```

Comment: thx for your help. I just want the data of first row and add the symbol into the dataframe.

Comment: IIUC, you can do `pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'symbol': dct['symbol'], **dct['annualReports'][0]}, 'index').T` or simply `pd.json_normalize(dct, 'annualReports', ['symbol']).iloc[[0]]
`

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
pd.DataFrame(dict_['annualReports']).assign(symbol=dict_['symbol'])
```

Output:

```
   Date Currency Revenue symbol
0  2019      USD     514    IFF
1  2018      USD     256    IFF
2  2017      USD     256    IFF
```

Comment: thx for your help. I just want the data of first row and add the symbol into the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I tried explicitly:

```
import pandas as pd

dic = {'symbol': 'IFF',
       'annualReports': 
           [{'Date': '2019', 'Currency': 'USD', 'Revenue': '514'},
            {'Date': '2018', 'Currency': 'USD', 'Revenue': '256'},
            {'Date': '2017', 'Currency': 'USD', 'Revenue': '256'}
]}

ar_list = dic['annualReports'].copy()
for ar_dic in ar_list:
    ar_dic['symbol'] = dic['symbol']

df = pd.DataFrame(ar_list)
print(df)
```

This gives:

```
   Date Currency Revenue symbol
0  2019      USD     514    IFF
1  2018      USD     256    IFF
2  2017      USD     256    IFF
```

Answer (score 0):

For this I would use a [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension) and [DataFrame.from_records()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html).  I'm also assuming you have a list of dicts like the one you describe, `dict_list = [d1, d2, ...]`, with variable numbers of annualReports but only one symbol per list.  The following should work:

```
record_list = [
  {
    'symbol': symbol_dict['symbol'],
    'Date': report['Date'],
    'Currency': report['Currency'],
    'Revenue': report['Revenue']
  }
  for symbol_dict in dict_list
  for report in symbol_dict['annualReports']
]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(record_list)
```

Also note you may want to do some type conversion / casting for the 'Revenue' and 'Date' fields. That's easily inserted into the list comprehension step.